# Installing a Nuget Package in an .sqlproj

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql, code-coverage, sqlproj

I want to install a nuget package (ReportGenerator) to help collate coverage reports across various projects in a solution in Azure. Some of these projects are SQL projects with unit tests undertaken with TsqlT. However I need to add a refernce to ReportGenerator in the test sqlProj projects.

Nuget package manager doesnt seem supported;

[image]

is there anyway I can add this package as a reference?

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag since this isn't really related to the SQL language.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is no way of achieving that with sql projects. If there is something that can meet your needs I'll start looking at Ed Elliot blog. https://the.agilesql.club

Comment: It seems like the solution would be to run ReportGenerator standalone as part of your build pipeline rather than packaging it in the project, but without more context it's hard to know whether this is applicable.